# simulation error of FMU with FMU_SDK

Tags: fmi

I tried to export the fmu that I created from the file.c and XML
But I do not know why I have this problem when I try to simulate" Illegal element outputs"

[image]

Comment: Please provide the FMU and the source code so that one can have a closer look and reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should run the FMU Compliance Checker (download it from http://fmi-standard.org/downloads/)  to see if errors in the FMU are detected.

Answer (score 0):

Mary had the problem declaring multiple ModelVariables inside the ModelDescription.xml. I think she solved the problem meanwhile.